# Uploading and viewing a picture with mySql and php

Tags: php, mysql, upload, image

Ok, im having trouble uploading and viewing a picture that im trying to use as "profile pictures"
When i upload the picture, i get no errors or anything, but when i got to the details page to see if its there, nothing is there, the phpmyadmin changes the imagedata for BLOB - NULL to BLOB - 0B, so something is happening but all the other attributes are empty, ie. the imagename, imagetype, imagesize. Without posting all my code cause there is quite alot of it, does anyone have any ideas on what it could be?

EDIT WITH CODE:

html for adding:

```
<tr><td>Profile Picture:</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="1000000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<input type="file" size="30" value="Image file" name="imagefile"></td></tr>
```

php for adding:

```
$profilepic = $_FILES['imagefile'];
$personid = add_person($username, $firstname, $lastname, $profilepic...etc);
```

diplaying the image:

```
<img src="get_image.php?id={$person.id}" {$person.imagesize} alt="{$person.imagename}">
```

in my add_person i have:

```
$image_details = process_uploaded_image_file($profilepic);
list($imagedata, $imagename, $imagetype, $imagewidthheight) = $image_details;
then i insert those into my database
```

and finally my get_image.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$image = getImage($id);

$data = $image['imagedata'];
$name = $image['imagename'];
$type = $image['imagetype'];
$size = strlen($data);

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $data;
```

thats about all i can post without the process image function and resizing etc.

EDIT WITH process_ipload_image_file:

```
function process_uploaded_image_file($image) {
// Check upload succeeded
if (!is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name']) || $image['size'] == 0) {
  return NULL;
} 

// Extract details
$imagedata = addslashes(file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']));
$imagename = addslashes(basename($image['name']));
$imagesize = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']); // an array
$imagewidthheight = addslashes($imagesize[3]); 
$imagetype = $imagesize['mime'];

// Check file is a JPEG
if ($imagetype != "image/jpeg") {
  return NULL;
}

/*
echo "Before resizing: name = $imagename, type = $imagetype, ", 
   "size = '$imagewidthheight'<br>\n";
*/

// Resize uploaded JPEG file, if necessary
// (shouldn't reuse name tmp.jpg repeatedly)
if ($imagesize[0] > MAX_WIDTH || $imagesize[1] > MAX_HEIGHT) {

    resize_image_file($image['tmp_name'], "images/tmp.jpg", 
                      MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
  list($width,$height) = getimagesize("images/tmp.jpg");
  $imagedata = addslashes(file_get_contents("images/tmp.jpg"));
  $imagewidthheight = "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
}

/*
echo "After resizing: name = $imagename, type = $imagetype, ", 
     "size = '$imagewidthheight'<br>\n";
*/

return array($imagedata, $imagename, $imagetype, $imagewidthheight);
}
```

Here is the resize function

```
/* Resize image into a width-height rectangle using GD library. */
function resize_image_file($src_file, $dst_file, $width, $height) {
// Compute new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($src_file);

 $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample $srcfile
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_file);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output resized image to $dst_file
imagejpeg($image_p, "$dst_file", 100);
}
```

Comment: post the essential code that handles the upload, it's hard to guess.

Comment: it is hard to pointout the issue without code snipset

Comment: Based on that code I am gonna have to go with the process_uploaded_image_file function as the culprit.

Comment: Please post full code of process_uploaded_image_file

Comment: ok, i edited my post to include them

Answer (score 1):

```
$imagedata = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($image['tmp_name'])));
```

Comment: Oh and use base64_decode() when you pull the image from the database. ie. base64_decode($row['image'])